# Function to uniquely map a set of rectangles in space to a number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

I am trying to build a new way of indexing spatial data.
Is there a function that takes as parameter a number of rectangles in euclidean space, and outputs an unique number?Can such a function be designed?

Example : 
I have 3 rectangles, with bounding boxes 
I1 = [**(0,0)**,(4,3)] 
I2 = [(1,1),(3,4)] 
I3 = [(2,2),(5,6)] .

f( I1, I2, I3 ) = 4657.

The function only outputs 4657 for this particular setup.

If, for example, I'1= [**(0,1)**,(4,3)], and I2 and I3 stay the same, 
f( I'1, I2, I3 ) = 4658.

The numbers are purely random.

Also, i am thinking about computationally generating random set ups,think 1.000.000 test cases, with 1.000.000+ rectangles, and constructing random equations.If there are no colliding function outcomes, then i know that i am on the right track.Would this be a good approach?

Comment: Are you assuming rectangles with integer coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a bijection $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$. Such things exist, but it's extremely doubtful that it would be useful for your purpose.

In practice your coordinates are probably not real numbers (but only floating point numbers). A good hash function (SHA-1 or MD-5 perhaps) could give you a one-way mapping which is 1-1 most of the time. That might be good enough for you, even though the inverse mapping is virtually impossible to compute. It depends on what you want to do with your data.

Comment: It seems to me the OP wants a bijection from $\{\text{set of subsets of } \mathbb{R}^4\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Possibly $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right, I misread him a bit. If he really wants a bijection from $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then he's out of luck. But in practice a good hash is still probably what he wants.

Comment: A hash would make the data impossible to decode, as you said.I think i have an idea for a way to store and retrieve data in almost O(1). It might be nothing, but it's worth a try.

Comment: mrf, why would i be out of luck with a bijection from R4 to R?The density of R would allow for such a thing to exist, at least that is what my intuition tells me.

Comment: A bijection from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$ exists (as I said in the post), but not from the power set of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (by cardinality reasons).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just dealing with positive integer coordinates and want a true bijection, then you can map using the prime numbers:
$$
f([(a,b),(c,d)],[(e,f),(g,h)],\cdots) = 2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d 11^e \cdots
$$

If negative integer coordinates are allowed, first map $a,b,c,\cdots$ using a bijection from the integers to the positive integers, and then do the same thing.

If you actually want *real* coordinates, refer to mrf's answer.

**Note:** You asked for a true bijection (you want $f$ to give a *unique* number), so I gave one.  However, I am skeptical that a true bijection will be useful to you since by nature it ends up having really large output values.  For example, in the example you give, we get
$$
f(I_1,I_2,I_3) = 641419005652623922014026079127112704375
$$
A hash table will probably be much more efficient.  You can also improve the bijection if you have some bound on the coordinates and/or the number of rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of using a Hilbert Curve to index each point of the 2D space. Then, to get the desired number consider mapping using powers of prime numbers for the corners of the squares.